# Memory mapping addresses using simple preprocessor define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a simple memory mapped interface, and I would like to write through
  this values to two registers and then read them back. The following code
  example works fine:

```
  volatile int *reg1 = (int *) 0x80000000;
  volatile int *reg2 = (int *) 0x80000004;

 *reg1 = 12; *reg2 = 23;  
 printf("reg1 = %i\n", *reg1);
 printf("reg2 = %i\n", *reg2);
```

Instead of "hardcoding" the addresses, I would like the address to be
  put together from a base address and an offset. Using some preprocessor
  statements, I want to have some defines.

**BEGIN UPDATE**

```
 #define WriteReg(BaseAddress, RegOffset, Data) \
  *((volatile int *)((char*)BaseAddress + RegOffset)) = (unsigned int)(Data)

 #define ReadReg(BaseAddress, RegOffset, Data) \
  (unsigned int)(Data) = *((volatile int *)((char*)BaseAddress + RegOffset))  


  WriteReg((int *) 0x80000000, 0, 18);
  WriteReg((int *) 0x80000000, 4, 29); 

  WriteReg((int *) 0x80000000, 4, res);
  printf("Reg2 = %i\n", res);

  WriteReg((int *) 0x80000000, 0, res);
  printf("Reg1 = %i\n", res);
```

**END UPDATE**

The output is now in either case 1073804536, instead of 12 and 23, respectively.
  So I assume I must have done something horrible wrong with the pointers, anyone
  a comment how I can properly build up this address with a define statement?

Comment: Why not make a function instead of a macro?

Comment: sure a possibility, but would be nice having a macro doing the job ;).

Comment: I updated the functions as suggested by AraK, however, the problem still remains. Any other comments to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Martin: No, it's _much_ nicer to have a function doing the job.

Answer (score 3):

You see, you are adding the offset as bytes. You either have to change your code to:

```
*((volatile int *)((char*)BaseAddress + RegOffset)) = (unsigned int)(Data)
```

Or, you can add the offset in-terms of your type:

```
  WriteReg(base, 0, 12);
  WriteReg(base, 1, 23);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the function accordingly as you suggested (see above). However, the problem still remains, I am not able to read back the correct value, the error remains more or less the same. Anyone an idea what could still be wrong with my pointers?

Answer (score 2):

As the pointer type is `int`, you should be adding 1 to it instead of 4 if you want to move to the next `int` in sequence. Remember, you are doing pointer arithmetic now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that since `base` is an `int*` when the macro expands to something like (the `ReadReg` macro being used in the example):

```
// ReadReg(base, 4, res)
res = *(base + 4)
```

You're adding 4 to an int pointer, which pointer arithmetic causes to increment by `(4 * sizeof(int))` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your macros as follows:

```
#define WriteReg(BaseAddress, RegOffset, Data) \
    *(unsigned*)((unsigned)BaseAddress + (unsigned)RegOffset) = (unsigned int)(Data)    

#define ReadReg(BaseAddress, RegOffset, Data) \
    Data = *(unsigned*)((unsigned)BaseAddress + (unsigned)RegOffset)
```

Answer (score 0):

This program as currently written uses `WriteReg` four times and `ReadReg` zero times.  Perhaps the second two times you intentded to invoke `ReadReg` instead of `WriteReg`.  `res` is uninitialized, so it's not surprising that it prints as a nonsensical value twice.  (It's also not declared, but I assume you just left that out.)

Answer (score 0):

```
  WriteReg((int *) 0x80000000, 4, res);
  printf("Reg2 = %i\n", res);
```

You write res to register, not read it. So res is still uninitialized.